# I want to find results on A and B

Tags: probability

**first exercise** : I have `P(AB)=0.1` and `P(A'B')=0.4` i must find `P(A)` and `P(B)`. 
I confess i have no idea about it.

**Second exercise** : I have another similar exercise that says i have `P(A)=0.2 and P(B)=0.3`
to find a)`P(A U B) ,b) P(A'B'),c) P(AB') and d) P(A'B)`
I have a) `P(A U B) =P(A)+P(B) =0.2+0.3=0.5` ok i think i am right to this
b)I know that

```
P(A)=0.2 so P(A')=1-P(A) => P(A')=1-0.2=0.8 
             P(B')=1-0,3=0.7
```

but P(A') and P(B') are together ,P(A'B')? i multiply or i sum them ? what now?

Comment: Knowing only $P(A\cap B)=0.1$ and $P(A'\cap B')=0.4$ that is not enough information to find $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ uniquely.  You need another piece of information.  All we can say for certainty is that $0.1\leq P(A)\leq 0.6$ and similarly for $P(B)$.

Comment: And in the second part of your question, $P(A \cup B) \neq P(A) + P(B) $. Its in fact equal to: $P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) $.

Comment: As for $P(A\cup B)$, you do not simply sum them.  $P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)\color{red}{-P(A\cap B)}$.  The only time when you are allowed to simply sum them is if you know they are mutually exclusive.  Further "*i multiply...?*"  No, $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$ is true if **and only if** $A$ and $B$ are independent events.  You may not simply multiply them if it is unknown.

Comment: i got confused moment P(A∩B)=0.1 where that comes from?

Comment: As for the second exercise, knowing only $P(A)$ and $P(B)$, there is not enough information to know any of $P(A\cup B), P(A'\cap B'), P(A\cap B'), P(A'\cap B)$.  You need an additional piece of information to know this, for example if you knew they were independent.

Comment: i have edited may you confused and the two exercises you did it 1

Comment: "*I got confused moment $P(A\cap B)=0.1$ where that comes from?*"  Presumably from the hypothesis in your problem statement.  Most problem statements begin "If you suppose ____ find ____"

Comment: P(A'∩B') is the same thing like P(A'B') ?

Comment: Yes... it is in my opinion the superior notation as it reminds you that what you are manipulating are technically sets.  $P(A'\cap B')$ and $P(A'B')$ and $Pr(A^c,B^c)$ and $\mathbb{P}(A^cB^c)$ and a number of other notations all mean the probability that neither event $A$ nor event $B$ occurred

Comment: @JMoravitz oh thanks i didn't see that in my book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probabilities for $A \cap B$ and $A^c \cap B^c$.

Draw a little Venn diagram to see that $A \cap B^c$ and $A^c \cap B$ are unspecified.

If we let $t = P(A \cap B^c)$, then since all probabilities sum to one we must have
$P(A^c \cap B) = 0.5-t$.

Since these are probabilities, we must have $t \ge 0$ and $t \le 0.5$.

Then $PA = P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap B^c) = 0.1+t$,
$PB = P(B \cap A) + P(B \cap A^c)=0.6-t$, with $t \in [0,0.5]$.

Comment: i didn't get anything you say it very mathematical .In the first exercise what it asks  i have P(AB)=0.1 and P(A'B')=0.4 and it asks me to find P(A) and P(B) .What about it?we cant find it ?

Comment: @m.s correct, we can not find it, at least not uniquely.  We need an additional piece of information.  What copper here did was to show that if we continued anyways and used one of those missing pieces of information despite the fact that we don't know the exact value and we called that value $t$, we could  then say what the values of $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are in terms of $t$.

Comment: thanks i have no idea the exercise was asking this